# Get youtube title from youtube xml or json

Tags: php, json, xml, youtube

im trying to get youtube video title from

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpe11FCFxBE&format=xml
```

in xml title is in

```
<oembed>
<title>
TITLE IS HERE
</title>
</oembed>
```

so i try this code to get title but it dont work

```
$json_output = file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id."&format=xml");
$fln = $json['oembed']['title'];
```

Comment: @Quentin He has typo in code.

Comment: How a string stored in `$json_output` become an associative array in `$json` ? Are you missing some code ?

Comment: @Makesh yes he has copied this from somewhere and has typo in it.

Comment: @VPS : My doubt is, is there any way to parse xml to json ? Thats why i asked has he used any API or method, to do such conversion ? Either he has to choose XML parsing or JSON parsing. Implementation is confusing little bit

Comment: @Makesh he used xml as format but trying json to parse, he just needs title from API call, so i provided him an answer but no reply yet.

Comment: @vps : Your answer will work ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code...

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id."&format=json");
$json_output = json_decode($content, true);
$fln = $json_output['title'];
```

You should use `format=json` if you want to parse json output.

Comment: not working   $content = file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id."&format=json");
$json_output = json_decode($content, true);
$fln = $json_output['title'];

Comment: try `var_dump($content)` and let me know what it outputs;